# Why does the golang place the type specifier "after" the variable name?

Tags: go

Just out of curiosity, why does the `golang` place the type specifier after the variable name like below. Have to? Or happen to?

```
type person struct {
    name string
    age  int
}
```

Why not just like this? It's more natural IMHO, and it saves the `type` keyword.

```
struct person {
    string name
    int age
}
```

Comment: You can found some reasons here: https://blog.golang.org/gos-declaration-syntax

Comment: The resource @sisoft provided is excellent (but doesn't explain where it comes from). My hunch is the following: since Go has three ancestors (CSP, Pascal/Oberon, and C) I suppose that the variable declaration and definition style is inherited from Pascal/Oberon line.

Comment: Second part of your question is simple: `type` defines more than just `struct`s.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I *think* the Go programming language follows these principles:

- declarations start with a keyword, so that the parser can be implemented with a single token look-ahead (like in Pascal)
- the rest of the declaration follows the English grammar, with every redundant word left out (also like in Pascal, but with fewer keywords)

Examples:

- The type `Frequency` is a `map` indexed by `string`, mapping to `int`
  `type Frequency map[string]int`
- The type `Point` is a `struct` with two fields, `x` and `y` of type `int`
  `type Point struct { x, y int }`

The above sentences focus more on the names than on the types, which makes sense since the names convey more meaning.

If I had to explain to novice programmers how to write declarations in Go, I would let them first describe it in plain English and then remove every word that *might even seem* redundant.

Up to now, I didn't find any contradictions to these rules.